# Electric-grade gel / silicone to provide physical protection for circuit boards from damage

Tags: heatsink, insulation, cases, mount

**Not** looking for a brand or product (unless allowed to ask) just the generic name for electric-grade gel / silicone that can be poured on the circuit board or embed the circuit-board in it.  It would serve as a *cushion* to provide **physical protection for circuit boards if dropped (2 meters) and/or the case moderately banged** so they won't get damaged.

The circuit-board is *inside an airtight metal case* and may be left out *on the sun for prolonged* periods.    It would also be a plus if the gel / silicone would act as a **heat sink** of sort to, although the circuit itself does not generate heat only from being baked in the sun inside a metal case.

Obviously, it has to be **non-conductive.**  It's ok if entombed for good, but would be great something that could be peeled off later.

Also, welcoming any other suggestions for PCB mounting to the metal case.

Thank you.

Comment: It seems to me that some judiciously placed soft silicone rubber stand-offs would make for good protection. Also, the case could be cooler by several degrees if it had a polished surface.

Comment: I don't know if it's usually silicon based, but it sounds like you may be talking about potting compound.  You put a board in a box, fill the box with goo, and hope you never have to repair it.  It's not a product I'm well versed in though.

Comment: Also consider painting the metal box with [ultra-white](https://www.purdue.edu/newsroom/releases/2021/Q2/the-whitest-paint-is-here-and-its-the-coolest.-literally..html) paint. New formulations exist which will reflect the vast majority of radiant heat. Will only help a little, but a little is better than none.

Comment: *Electronic Potting Compound* - too expensive for drop protection. Maybe to waterproof a small circuit. https://www.amazon.com/Flexible-Urethane-2-Part-Potting-Compound/dp/B07R4XV4K8

Comment: Thank you all for the recommendations, explanations and links.  I have a good direction to follow now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **... just the generic name ...**

You might be looking for a "[conformal coating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_coating)" and/or "[potting compound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potting_(electronics))"

> Conformal coating material is a thin polymeric film which conforms to the contours of a printed circuit board to protect the board's components. Typically applied at 25-250 μm1 thickness, it is applied to electronic circuitry to **protect against** moisture, dust, chemicals, and **temperature extremes.**

> In electronics, potting is a process of filling a complete electronic assembly with a solid or gelatinous compound for high voltage assemblies by excluding gaseous phenomena such as corona discharge, **for resistance to shock** and vibration, and for the exclusion of water, moisture, or corrosive agents.

(my emphasis in both paragraphs)

Using either of the phrases  "conformal coating" and/or "potting compound" as a search term will find a range of available products.

Comment: Thank you all for the explanation and recommendations!  Yes, it's the potting / conforming compound that I think will do the best job in protecting inside the enclosure from bangs, etc     I am already using liquid tape for hard to reach places, but something more opaque would work better.

Answer (score 1):

I use Liquid Tape in many of my circuits. It is like a rubber coating which can provide mechanical protection and also electrical isolator. You have it available as a spray on as well as manually applied with a brush. It is also easy to peel off later. Not sure how good of a thermal conductor it will be. It will probably act more as a thermal isolator.

Comment: Thank you.  I am already using liquid tape for hard to reach places, but something more opaque and less messy would work better for larger spaces.  So, albeit I will keep using the liquid tape, a potting compound seems a good bet also for filling the enclosure.